# Get data in php page from json data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an HTML form that I convert to JSON and pass it to another page `save.php`. The issue is that I can't see the data on the `save.php` page.

My code for the HTML form:

```
<form id="my-profile" action="save.php">
    <div id="accordion" style="width:80%; margin:0 auto;background:">
        
        <div class="s_panel">
            <div>
                <h3 style="width:100% ;background: gray;margin-top:5px">
                    <input type="text" class="TEER" maxlength="20" id="item" style="height:35px;width:20%;padding:5px;" placeholder="Enter title , ex (basic information) " name="sec4" value="Works">
                    <input class="ed" type="button" style="float:right;height:35px;width:100px;" value="Edit">
                </h3>
                <textarea name="sec4[asd]" style="height:200px"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            height: 'fill',
            header: "h3",
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var order = $("#accordion").sortable("toArray");
                $('#image_order').val(order.join(","));
                alert($('#image_order').val());
            }
        }).sortable({
            items: '.s_panel'
        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ahmed() {
        $("#btnSerialize").on("click", function() {

            var obj = $('form').serializeJSON();
            console.log(obj);

            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
            $("#result").val(jsonString);
            var xht = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xht.open("POST", "save.php");
            xht.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "Application/json");
            xht.send(jsonString);

        })
    });

</script>
```

In the `save.php` I use the following code:

```
$json=file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I am unable to print the content on the `save.php` page.

What am I missing? How can I display the output of the HTML form in the `save.php` file?

Comment: [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns a string it does not print out anything. You have to output it. Besides, it expects a filename or an URL to a file as param.

Comment: Thank you for you response I must make my research cause I don't now how to do that thanx for help